# Interrupting an input in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, input

I want to stop an input. Where the user inputs a string of a certain length then python "presses enter for them," and cuts the input short.

```
print("[Play]  Cheats  Credits  ", end='')
inp=input("")
if inp=="d":
    print("Play  [Cheats]  Credits  ", end='')
    inp=input("")
if inp=="a":
    ...
```

I would like it to take the input instantly after the user inputs a single letter. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is a nonblocking raw-input. It's implementation differs from OS to OS. The this post for a starting point: http://repolinux.wordpress.com/2012/10/09/non-blocking-read-from-stdin-in-python/#select